# How to send signal with Testcontainers?

Tags: testcontainers

I use `haproxy` [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/haproxy/) and mount config file.

The config gets regenerated and I would like to restart `haproxy` by sending `docker kill -s HUP %container%`. How can I achieve this with Testcontainers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While TestContainers simplifies the creation of Docker containers for testing, it also exposes the underlying [docker-java client](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java), which gives you an access to almost all Docker APIs.

e.g. your case:

```
container.getDockerClient()
    .killContainerCmd(container.getContainerId())
    .withSignal("HUP")
    .exec()
```